# Azure DevOps Server 2019 extension: How do I limit the work item data entry forms my custom page appears on?

Tags: json, customization, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm using Azure Devops Server 2019, update 1.1. My goal is to write an extension that presents a new page, but **only** on the user story work item data entry form and not the data entry form for a Task, Bug, Issues, etc. See screen shot

[image]

Here is the contributions section of my vss-extension.json (It's what produced the custom page in the screen shot above). I've read [Extension manifest reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops), but I can't find a setting related to limiting which form a new page appears on.

Does anyone know which area of the extensions architecture I need to work in to limit which forms on which a new page appears?

```
"contributions": [
    {  
        "id": "sample-work-item-form-page",
        "type": "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-page",
        "description": "Custom work item form page",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "Create Standard Tasks",
            "uri": "workItemPage.html"
        } 
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reference to this doc: [Extend the work item form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-workitem-extension?view=azure-devops-2019), this web extension belongs to  Azure Boards service, so it will appear in all work item pages as your mentioned doc: [Extension manifest reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops-2019). Currently it is not documented to specify which work item type it appears in.

In addition, you could directly follow this doc: [Customize the web layout for a work item type (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-form?view=azure-devops-2019#add-a-custom-page) to add a custom page to the user story work item.
[image]

Comment: So, just to be clear: If I want to add a new page using a custom extension, I cannot control which work item forms it appears on. Alternatively, I can use a custom process template (via inheritance) and create a custom page for only the user story, but then that's not a custom extension, i.e., I can add fields to the custom page, but cannot otherwise "program" the page to do custom operations like I could do using a custom extension

Comment: Yeah, that is the current limitation but it is a good suggestion, we suggest that you could submit it here: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=22, the product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap.